# Evaluate: $\int e^x.\sin (x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate: $\int e^x.\sin (x) dx$

My Attempt;
$$=\int e^x.\sin (x) dx$$
$$=\sin (x).e^x - \int \cos (x).e^x dx$$
Neither of $\cos (x)$ and $e^x$ is going to vanish although we keep on using By Parts. 
How to procced further?

Comment: Do parts again or complexify integral

Comment: Hint: Differentiate the trig function on the right a second time (another integration by parts), and note that you have (up to sign difference, which can be remedied by moving the sign to the outside of the integral) a copy of  what you started with. you should be able to manipulate the equation to get $2\cdot$ (the integral you started with)=(stuff), and thus easily find your solution.